# ClientDisconnected due to error: Timeout UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkIdentity:UNetStaticUpdate()

Tags: unity, c#, multiplayer, unity-networking

Why am I getting this error. I think it has problem with port so I change port number and still getting same error. yesterday it was working fine but when I start today it giving me error like this.

> ClientDisconnected due to error: Timeout
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkIdentity:UNetStaticUpdate()

I refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268495/server-disconnected-due-to-error-timeout) but, there is not any answer presence for this error.